# boolean initialize parameter of class.forName method in java

Tags: java, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

Although I read the documentation, I'm not able to understand what is the difference here between those two lines of java codee when loading a class:

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName("jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror", false, enginClassLoader);


Class<?> cls = Class.forName("jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror", true, enginClassLoader);
```

here the boolean  parameter is explained in the documentation as follows:

> initialize if true the class will be initialized. See Section 12.4 of
>   The Java Language Specification.

In my case, even if i use the code with false parameter, it still works. So I wanted to know when it should be true then?

Comment: The class is initialized only if the initialize parameter is true and if it has not been initialized earlier.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739726/class-way-of-obtaining-class-does-it-initialize-the-class would be helpful for you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the referenced chapter of the JLS states:

> Initialization of a class consists of executing its static
>   initializers and the initializers for static fields (class variables)
>   declared in the class.
>
> Initialization of an interface consists of executing the initializers
>   for fields (constants) declared in the interface.
>
> Before a class is initialized, its direct superclass must be
>   initialized, but interfaces implemented by the class are not
>   initialized. Similarly, the superinterfaces of an interface are not
>   initialized before the interface is initialized.

So the first call would not run any static initializers for fields and constants like  `private static String x = "this is my value";` leaving x null and to be initialized later, whicle the second one would set x to the desired value.

Creating an object from this class is the latest point where the JVM will initialize the class on its own, if this was skipped until then.

Comment: Actually, `private String x` would not be affected, since it’s an instance field.  `private static String x`, however, would be affected.  Also there will never be a time when `x` is seen as null, because reading `x` would require the class being initialized.

Comment: It’s misleading to label “creating an object from this class” as the “latest point” of class initialization. As @VGR already said, you’ll never perceive the field `x` to be `null` outside of a class initializer, as accessing a `static` field of the class will trigger its initialization as well. [All possible triggers are explicitly specified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50347325/2711488).